# Is $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^+$ a compact Polish space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

if $X$ is defined by $$X= [0,+\infty)\cup\{+\infty\}$$ is endowed with the metric
$$d_X(x,y) = |\arctan(x) - \arctan(y)|$$ Is it true that the metric space $(X,d_X)$ meets the following properties?

1. separable
2. complete (for this metric)
3. compact.

It seems to me that it holds, but i didn't see it written explicitly, so i have a doubt.

Comment: "It seems to me that it holds" Why? What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. With that metric it's homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ with the usual metric, so it's compact, separable, and metrizable. A compact metrizable space is automatically complete in every compatible metric.